# Activity won't load content quickly enough

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to make a splash screen for my Android app, where the login page just starts the Splash activity, and then all the login processing stuff is done there. It then returns a boolean whether login succeeded or not. But the login processing completes before the XML layout content loads. How can this be fixed?

This is my splash screen activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null)
    {
        url = extras.getString("url");
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    url += "login/?userName=" + Login.loginName + "&password=" + Login.password;

    DomLoginParser parser = new DomLoginParser(url);
    if(parser.parse())
    {
        Login.loginSuccessful = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Login.loginSuccessful = false;
    }

    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the login out of the onCreate call by using AsyncTask to perform the login.
What you are doing is finishing the activity before giving it a chance to show the contents.
The activity is showing the contentView only after the onCreate call is finished...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what DomLoginParser do, and thinking that the Login class is static, but why do you call the finish() method inside the onCreate() ?

That's the problem, you kill the activity immediately!

Remove the finish() invocation.

If

```
DomLoginParser parser = new DomLoginParser(url);
if(parser.parse())
{
    Login.loginSuccessful = true;
}
else
{
    Login.loginSuccessful = false;
}
```

this is all you do about login, and want to have the splash screen visible for some time, call a Thread.sleep() (but be aware that it can produce Application Not Responding if sleeping for too much time), or simply create a separate process (Asynctask or threadhandler associated with another thread that say to your splash screen to finish).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private class LoginChecker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 

         protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) { 
              DomLoginParser parser = new DomLoginParser(url);    
              if(parser.parse())    {   
                  Login.loginSuccessful = true;    
              }    else    {        
                  Login.loginSuccessful = false;    
              }    
             return null;     
         }     

         protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {         
           // finish the activity    
         } 

    }
```

To call this, update  your onCreate method to something along the lines of:

```
@Override        
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                   
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                    
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
      if(extras !=null) {                
         url = extras.getString("url");            
      }                    
      setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);            
      url += "login/?userName=" + Login.loginName + "&password=" + Login.password;                    
      new LoginChecker.execute();
}
```